# Customized legend not showing in geoserver ol3

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

Recently we were stuck with updating legend with customized sld but we were not able to get customized colors in legend.

The code was as below

```
if (layers[i].get('showLegend') === true) {
    try {
        var url = layers[i].getSource().getUrls()[0];
    } catch (err) {
        var url = layers[i].getSource().getUrl();
    }
    var legendImg = document.createElement('img');
    //var str = url + '?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.0.0&layer=' + layers[i].getSource().getParams().layers + '&format=' + format+'&SLD_BODY='+sld+'&legend_options=fontSize:13;fontName:san-sarif;bgColor:0xdddddd;forceLabels:on'+'&WIDTH=12&HEIGHT=12&Scale=1';

    var str = url + '?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.0.0&SLD_BODY:' + sld + '&layer=' + layers[i].getSource().getParams().layers + '&format=' + format + '&legend_options=fontSize:13;fontName:san-sarif;bgColor:0xdddddd;forceLabels:on' + '&WIDTH=12&HEIGHT=12&Scale=1';
    // str=str.replace("<","&lt;").replace(">","&gt;").replace("/","%2f");
    alert(sld1);
    legendImg.src = str;
    legendDiv.appendChild(legendImg);
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    legendDiv.appendChild(br);
}
```

We are getting square box with text Grey polygon with black outline which is default sld, new sld is in other color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakenly : was typed instead of =, rest is working.

```
SLD_BODY=' + encodeURIComponent(sld)+ '&layer='...
```